# Tensorflow 2.3 / 2.2 - Import / Export Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

Hi when trying to import a model with Tensorflow 2.2 (on arm, nvidia jetson) which was created with Tensorflow 2.3 (x86), I get the following error:

```
File "Anomaly.py", line 50, in anomaly_detection
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model.h5')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
return hdf5format.loadmodelfromhdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5format.py", line 178, in loadmodelfromhdf5
customobjects=customobjects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/modelconfig.py", line 55, in modelfrom_config
return deserialize(config, customobjects=customobjects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 109, in deserialize
printablemodulename='layer')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/genericutils.py", line 373, in deserializekeras_object
list(custom_objects.items())))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 398, in from_config
customobjects=customobjects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 109, in deserialize
printablemodulename='layer')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/genericutils.py", line 375, in deserializekeras_object
return cls.fromconfig(clsconfig)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/baselayer.py", line 655, in fromconfig
return cls(**config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 453, in init **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 127, in init **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in methodwrapper
result = method(self, args, *kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 294, in init
genericutils.validatekwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/genericutils.py", line 792, in validatekwargs
raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')
```

The model looks similar to this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding="same",input_shape=(window,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
...
```

I tried both ***.tf*** and ***.h5*** for saving the model.
I think the error is related to different keras versions, however I don't want to (can) change the keras versions on any of the machines.
Is there a way to resolve this compatibility problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Best regards,
Dominik

Comment: did you try to import the model in the machine which you created the model?

Comment: Also, it is advised that you use the Tensorflow saved model format in TF2. Can you try using the saved model format instead of .h5?

Comment: I tried both .tf and .h5. For both I get the same error

Comment: Importing the model on the machine where I created it is no problem.

Comment: not the .tf format. Saved Model. Check this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: Also when saving the model with saved_model and loading it again with tf.keras.models.load_model, the error stays the same

Comment: you should load with `tf.saved_model.load`. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#loading_and_using_a_custom_model

Comment: I did that, but then I can not use model.predict etc.